# ASP.Net core web app not unloading other Razor Assembly which were loaded dynamically

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, assembly-loading, dynamic-assemblies, assemblyloadcontext

I am having a razor web app where few other razor web app are added dynamically using AssemblyLoadContext

`Assembly assembly = _loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(pluginLocation);`

Since razor app assembly are added over run time it was required to add assembly to AddApplicationPart.
`_builder.AddApplicationPart(assembly);`

After doing above steps I am able to browse through dynamically added razor web apps.

Issue occurred for when unloading the dynamically added assembly(razor web app).

Steps that I did to unload the assembly(razor web app) are

- Removed **CompiledRazorAssemblyPart** and **AssemblyPart** from **ApplicationPartManager**
- Unload AssemblyLoadContext using **_loadContext.Unload()**
- Garbage collection using **GC.Collect()**

Even after doing the above steps dynamically loaded razor web app URL's/pages are accessible. Please suggest a solution to remove the assemblies.

Comment: Why do you want to remote the assemblies after you load it?

Comment: @XinranShen Each module of the application is created as separate Razor web app. So inorder to block the access to that module/feature I am plannig to unload the assemblies. I need to do this in runtime so that its not required to restart the Kestrel.

Comment: From MS Docs, To unload an assembly in the .NET Framework, you must unload all of the application domains that contain it. To unload an application domain, use the AppDomain.Unload method. For more information, see How to: [Unload an application domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-unload-an-application-domain). Hope it can give you some help.

Comment: @XinranShen I am using .net core web app. In .net core Only 1 AppDomain is allowed. When try to create a new app domain or Unload exiting App domain it will throw error